# django throwing ImproperlyConfigured error while importing data using 'django-import-export' library

Tags: django, django-admin, django-import-export

I'm trying to import data into a model through django admin using dajngo-import-export library, though I'm facing "Improperly Configured" error.
This is the error message:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/pages/quote/import/
No exception message supplied
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/pages/quote/import/
Django Version: 3.0
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Location: C:\Users\Dell\.virtualenvs\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py in import_data, line 737
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Dell\.virtualenvs\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\read_bus',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\dell\\anaconda3\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\dell\\anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\Downloads\\read_bus',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\.virtualenvs\\read_bus-UfMQ3ck8\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',]
```

I'm following the documentation as mentioned [here](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

This is the admin.py file:

```
class QuoteResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model =Quote
        import_id_fields=('quote',)
        fields = ('quote','book','author',)

class QuoteAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display=('quote','book','author')
    resource_class =QuoteResource

admin.site.register(Quote,QuoteAdmin)
```

I've tried with and without 'QuoteResource', without success.

I'm successfully able to export the data from admin. But facing challenge during import. Snip of admin during import:
[image]

Following is one of the various ways in which I tried to import data:

[image]

Does it has somthing to do with the django settings or the csv data format?

Let me if you need any more information.

Comment: Your error comes from import export trying to use database transactions but transactions not being supported. What database are you using? https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L737

Comment: I'm using MySQL database...

Comment: Well it doesn't look like it supports transactions. Add the setting & make it false; `IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS`. You can see that here; https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L44

Comment: Great!! It worked. Thanks man @markwalker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error comes from import export trying to use database transactions but transactions not being supported. So this is an issue with your database.

The section of code from django-import-export can be seen here:  https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L737

To disable transactions, add the setting & make it false; `IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS`.

You can see that here; https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/blob/master/import_export/resources.py#L44